# Authenticate! is changing username/password combo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with Sorcery to implement an activation email. Currently I'm able to create the User and have the activation email send, but when the link contained in the email and it read "User Activated" it changes the Username/Password combo that was originally used. I am using my own methods to create a "user", the only submodule of Sorcery being used is user_activation. I'm hoping someone smarter than me can see what is going on with the Username/Password when Authenticate! is called?

Sorcery is [Here](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/model.rb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't definitively say this is causing the problem, but as your username attribute is called `name` rather than `username` (the Sorcery default), you should have the line

```
user.username_attribute_names = [:name]
```

in `config/initializers/sorcery.rb`

Comment: Changed the attribute to :name, but the problem is still there.

Comment: How is the username being changed (i.e. from what to what)?

Comment: I changed it from, 
# user.username_attribute_names = [:username] 
to,
user.username_attribute_names = [:name]
restarted the server and tried again

Comment: No sorry I mean how is sorcery/authenticate! changing the username

Comment: I think it's changing the password. I believe it's encrypting the password differently when a "user" is activated. I could be wrong, but this is my suspicion.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth double checking (e.g. compare the value of `encrypted_password` before and after activation)

Comment: Checked it. They are different before/after activation. I'll play around with it here. If you have any more suggestions let me know. Thanks for your help.